# Android AutoCompleteTextView , no manual entry

Tags: android

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#AutoComplete

I am using an AutoCompleteTextView to get my predefined words as suggestions. I have a requirment that for the user, only the words from my predefined list is allowed. ( Like stackoverflow Tags )
How can I prohibit the user from entering those?

Comment: you can use `Spinner` instead `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Comment: user should be able to type. spinner allows that?

Comment: @PerolthDasappan: "for the user, only the words from my predefined list is allowed". And you are using Auto complete. Then why should he type it? Spinner is best option.

Comment: @PerolthDasappan No spinner doesn't allow that. But if the option should be not editable then spinner is the best option.